# Why doesn't Dor Hamabul deserve the World to Come?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, parashat-noach, olam-haba-world-to-come, mabul

The Mishna ([Sanhedrin 10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.107b.18?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.2&lang2=bi&w2=Bartenura&lang3=en)) states that Dor Hamabul do not have a part in the world to come:

> דּוֹר הַמַּבּוּל אֵין לָהֶם חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא וְאֵין עוֹמְדִין בַּדִּין
>   The generation of the flood has no portion in the world to come

In my understanding, the punishment cleanses the sins, and the person is "free to continue". At least this is how it works for us, Jews.

On the other hand, G-d openly admits, that their sins stemmed from the evil inclination He initially implanted in all of them, so I suppose the punishment is sufficient.

Why don't they deserve a portion in the WTC?

Comment: I do not think this question is answerable.

Comment: You can read here the difference between the punishment of the Dor Hamabul and the Dor Hahaflagah, very interesting, it might answer your question, I can't summarize, so please take a look at: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/68625/jewish/Likkutei-Sichot-Noach.htm